# Filter Custom Dimension with Period in Property Name

Tags: azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

Following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-tour#custom-properties-and-measurements), I see how to filter on custom dimensions but how do I filter when there is a '.' in the key / property name?

For example, I want to filter on `ServiceFabric.ServiceTypeName` from this custom dimension value:

```js
{
    "AspNetCoreEnvironment": "Production",
    "ServiceFabric.ApplicationTypeName": "MyCompany.MyAppType",
    "ServiceFabric.ServiceTypeName": "MyService",
    "ServiceFabric.ApplicationName": "fabric:/MyCompany.MyApp",
    "ServiceFabric.PartitionId": "some-guid",
    "ServiceFabric.ServiceName": "fabric:/MyCompany.MyApp/MyService",
    "ServiceFabric.InstanceId": "55555",
    "ServiceFabric.NodeName": "my-node",
    "CategoryName": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost",
    "Protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
    "Host": "MyCompany.com",
    "Method": "GET",
    "Scheme": "https",
    "Path": "/api/values"
}
```

---

The following is not working...

```
traces
| extend type = customDimensions.ServiceFabric.ApplicationTypeName
| where type == "MyCompany.MyAppType"
| order by timestamp  desc
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the syntax for names with special things is:

```
customDimensions["ServiceFabric.ApplicationTypeName"]
```

you can use that bracket+quotes thing to name columns as well:

```
| extend ["This is a column with spaces"] = blah
```

or

```
| project-rename ["Name with space"] = name
```

from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/schema-entities/entity-names#reference-identifiers-in-queries

- Identifiers names that include special characters (such as `-`) must be enclosed using `['` and `']` or using `["` and `"]`.
- Identifier names that are language keywords must be enclosed using `['` and `']` or `["` and `"]`.
- Identifier names that are literals must be enclosed using `['` and `']` or `[" and "]`.
- Note: Identifiers are case-sensitive. For example, you can't refer to a table called `ThisTable` as `thisTABLE`.

Comment: Any chance you know where that is documented?

Comment: the only place i can find that syntax *explicitly* documented is on dynamic https://docs.loganalytics.io/docs/Language-Reference/Data-types/dynamic .  I've requested internally for it be explicitly added to `extend`, `project`, etc, or more generically somewhere that explains escaping of column names, because yeah, i can't find it.

Comment: found it!  https://docs.loganalytics.io/docs/Learn/References/Naming-principles  (AI and LA share the same underlying database technology, only the schemas are different)

Comment: Really appreciate you digging that up!  FYI, I submitted a [PR](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/pull/7088) to the docs.

Comment: [Documentation updated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-tour#custom-properties-and-measurements) via [Azure Docs PR: 7088](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/pull/7088)!  Thanks John!

Comment: Hi John G. - the doc links don't work anymore & I'm having trouble finding them on https://learn.microsoft.com/.  Any ideas?  thanks!

Comment: updated link to point at learn.microsoft.com: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/schema-entities/entity-names#reference-identifiers-in-queries